# A new colleague told me he does not want to stay with our company? Should I inform my manager?

Tags: professionalism, communication

My question is different from [this and is not a duplicate](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/should-i-inform-my-manager-that-a-colleague-is-looking-for-another-job-if-i-was) because

1) I am not friends with the mentioned guy

2) I am the new team lead for the project and i am suppose to invest time in training this guy.Why should i do that if he already told me he wants to leave the project.

A new colleague who is still in the university, so basically doing a 50% student job with us, told me that he does not want to stay with our company for more than 6 months. He said that he does not want to work with the technology which we are using. He said he mentioned about another project in our department during his interview (in which i was not present but the current project lead and my manager were present). We have offered him a 1 year contract on the hope of getting him trained here so that if he chooses, he can work with us after he completes his studies.

He is in the company for only 6 weeks so far and i am already having social, behavioral and political problems with him. I am suppose to be the team lead for our project after 2 weeks and having known all this, he confided his plans with me. i was already spending time training him right now and it was not very helpful that he said all this to me.

We have no personal relationship or sharing at all. He started by saying that he wants to be honest and does not want to hide anything. Than he told me how he does not want to work with us, citing his interest for some other technology as a reason. Than he suddenly requested me not to share this information with anybody. This sudden jump from being all honest to 'not tell anybody' made me baffled. I told him at this point to stop and share this kind of information with the boss(manager) to which he said he already did it in the interview.

Now i am confused and i am pretty sure the boss and the current team lead have no idea about it. The guy than went on counting the stuff that he wants to learn from us like server management and a bit about data analytic, the work he wants to use in the next company he desires to join.

He is already shying away to finish the work on tickets that he started and i think its because  he does not see the time spend on this work as relevant to his future job.

My guess is that he wants me to favor him by giving him the work of his choice. I don't see this as possible as we are already low on coding power and i don't want to favour someone over my project(which i have to lead now.) I am confused as to how should i handle the situation? should i already talk to my manager to look for his alternative as well. My problem is that i have already given a negative feed back about him to my boss(without being asked - so like a complaint). Now does it look like a personal vengeance or dislike if i say all this stuff again?

Comment: @JimG He's not a colleague, but a direct report.

Comment: What action would you like your manager to take if you do report him? Fire him right away? Keep him around for a couple of months without giving him anything important to do? Something else? If he is directly reporting to you, can you do the same by yourself without involving your manager?

Answer (score -1):

It is not just appropriate that you report this information to your manager, probably your responsibility to make this report.

You are this persons supervisor, and they told you that they would be leaving in 6 months.  It is unlikely but, possible that this could be considered notice, unless you are paid to make that determination, best to let the people who are deal with it.  What is likely, is that in 5 or 6 months when this person has responsibilities, they will quit.  And when they do they will let someone know that you were told 6 months earlier about the planned departure.

So, protect your self from [Murphy](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) and just report what was said to your manager, and let them deal with it as they see fit.